# iOS component reusability: views and view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Very basic question that I can't seem to find a straight answer for.

So here's the deal: I have a piece of a UI that I want to reuse in a couple interfaces. In particular, it should be contained as a subview within a parent view that is part of a navigation stack, but also usable as a standalone modal view. The child view in question is just a customized UITableView with its databinding methods implemented by the child controller.

The child view should be bound to a particular model object where it gets all of its data from. In other words, the controller for it implements the necessary databind methods for the UITableViewDataSource based on that target model object.

It seems obvious to me that I need to create a controller to represent this embeddable child view, since the implementation of those databind methods are the same in all instances, but it appears that pre iOS 5 (I currently need to support iOS 4+) it's strongly recommended against embedding view controllers within other view controllers.

This is totally counter-intuitive to the MVC pattern Apple *supposedly* employs in Cocoa (I am still not convinced what they've implemented is MVC at all). If I'm not allowed to embed sub view-controllers, how am I supposed to reuse the databinding/model logic of my child view controller in different parent interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a view controller to provide data, you can create a controller class (just a regular `NSObject` subclass) and instantiate *that* for each view controller that needs to embed your subview.

EDIT: So you would do something like `[[MyController alloc] initWithTableView:tableView]`.

Comment: ...and who creates the tableView?

Comment: Oh I see, I would just add the tableView to each parent interface I need it for, then "bind" that to my data source using an instance of this custom controller class. Ok that might work.

Comment: Or you could just have a `tableView` property on `MyController`…you would instantiate a MyController object in your view controller's initializer method and store it in an instance variable. Then in `viewDidLoad`, you would set the `tableView` property with your brand new `UITableView` object.